# PostgreSQL installer doesn't start on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-10

I downloaded PostgreSQL 14 from https://content-www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads for 64 Bit Windows (that's my system) but after I double-clicked on its icon there's no setup window showing. The only thing that happened was a logo window that showed up for a few seconds and after that was gone with no error windows.

I tried running the installer as administrator but with the same effects.
I also checked if antivirus isn't blocking the installer and it is not the case.
I downloaded version 13.4 and tried to run the installer but the same results as before.

I don't know what else can I do since there's no specific error that I can check. Could anyone help with that?

Comment: Is there anything logged in the eventlog?

Comment: There's nothing related in the eventlog but I checked antiviruses once again and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The McAfee antivirus blocked running of the PostgreSQL installer even though it was inactive and didn't generate any errors/notifications. I totally removed it and after that the installer is working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).